# Using TreeVew to navigate to different pages

Tags: wpf, binding, treeview

I would like to make a `Settings` window similar to the `Options` box in VS2012. I expect to write a XAML page for each set of settings. But how do I use a `TreeView` to choose which XAML page gets shown? Should the XAML page be part of the objects that are loaded in the tree?

(I should say, how do I do this in an MVVM way... if possible.)

Comment: Is the issue you are having beyond binding your `TreeViewItems` to objects that contain the URL of the XAML pages?

Answer (score 0):

I would do it along the lines of the following:

Have a view model class, call it something like `SettingsPageVM`, which contains a `Title` and `PageUrl` to your page.

Having created a list of your `SettingsPageVM`, bind it to your `TreeView` with a list called something like `Items`, with a `HierarchicalDataTemplate`, such as:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:SettingsPageVM}" ItemsSource="{Binding Items, Mode=OneWay}">
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Content="{Binding Title}" Command="Open"/>
    </StackPanel>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Then, bind the open command to handle navigating to your page:

```
<UserControl.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="Open" CanExecute="OpenCanExecute" Executed="OpenExecuted"></CommandBinding>
</UserControl.CommandBindings>
```

Is the issue you are having deeper than this?

Comment: Is a PageUrl related to a page class?

Comment: No, it's just a property (whatever you want to call it) in your view model class to hold the url to navigate to.